# River flow downhill

Tags: point, elevation, line

I have polylines (rivers) with assigned elevations. I need to ensure they are flowing  downstream and indicate which vertices are incorrect. I do not have 3D analyst, spatial analyst, or network analyst.

Comment: Does this have to be completed in ArcGIS? If you are willing to use alternative GIS applications, you can look at free and open source solutions, such as QGIS and Grass. There are lots of examples of how to do this online, and in this forum.

Comment: Theank you for your comment. I am downloading QGIS now. What would be the correct terminology to search for in the QGIS forum? Is there a tool or methodology you can point me towards? Thank you.

Comment: When you say assigned with elevation, are these fields such as the FROM and TO end with an elevation or is it a PolylineZ feature class and each vertex of a polyline has an XYZ value?

Comment: The PolylineZ feature class and each vertex of a polyline has an XYZ value